# Get selected value of option with multiple dropdown menus using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I have multiple features that have multiple options that need to be updated when an option is selected. I also need to pass a third piece of data through the attribute element.

`.getElementById()` works for a single dropdown menu, but how do I get it to work when there are multiple menus on the page?

I have tried `var e = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass");` which did not work.

I also tried to create `optionsText` & `optionsValue` in the same way that `optionsFtr` is created with `var optionsValue = $('option:selected', this).value;` and that didn't work either.

http://jsfiddle.net/8awqLek4/4/

HTML Code

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="ftrsTitle">BODY</div>
        <select class="testClass" id="testId">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ftr="bod" value="blk">Black</option>
            <option ftr="bod" value="grn">Kelly Green</option>
            <option ftr="bod" value="red">Red</option>
            <option ftr="bod" value="roy">Royal</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ftrsTitle">TRIM</div>
        <select class="testClass">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ftr="trm" value="blk">Black</option>
            <option ftr="trm" value="grn">Kelly Green</option>
            <option ftr="trm" value="red">Red</option>
            <option ftr="trm" value="roy">Royal</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="vars"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on('change', function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("testId");
        var optionsText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var optionsValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var optionsFtr = $('option:selected', this).attr('ftr');
        $("#vars").html("<p>optionsText: " + optionsText + "</p><p>optionsValue: " + optionsValue + "</p><p>optionsFtr: " + optionsFtr + "</p>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read select value you can simply use `$(this).val()`. To get selected option label you should use `text()` method.

Fixed code looks like this:

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
    var optionsText = $('option:selected', this).text();
    var optionsValue = $(this).val();
    var optionsFtr = $('option:selected', this).attr('ftr');
    $("#vars").html("<p>optionsText: " + optionsText + "</p><p>optionsValue: " + optionsValue + "</p><p>optionsFtr: " + optionsFtr + "</p>");
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8awqLek4/3/

Comment: Oh sweet, I just figured out this convoluted method of finding the ID and then referencing that: `var selectId = this.id; var e = document.getElementById(selectId);` http://jsfiddle.net/8awqLek4/6/ But this is way better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on('change', function(){
                var e = $(this).find("option:selected");
                $("#vars").html("<p>optionsText: " + e.text() + "</p><p>optionsValue: " + $(this).val() + "</p><p>optionsFtr: " + e.attr("ftr") + "</p>");
        });
});
```

use the `this` keyword. Than you can access the select targeted, and with find in combination with the `:selected` selector you can find the option element currently selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/8awqLek4/5/