# Javascript not working on any Internet Explorer version

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie programmer but I was assign a project and I am having trouble getting this code to work on Internet Explorer. It works on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  In the Developer console in IE, it keeps saying s1 is undefined.  I found the JavaScript code on stack's overflow.  Basically what I want is if the user answer Yes to any of the question, it will redirect them to page, and if they answer No to all the questions it will redirect them to a different page.

```
        <div>
          <label> A. Are you a programmer?</label>
          <select id="s1" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> B. Are you over 18?</label>
          <select id="s2" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> C. Do you like apples?</label>            
          <select id="s3" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>    


<script>

  function gotoPage(){

  if(s1.value == "Yes" || s2.value == "Yes" || s3.value == "Yes") {
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
  } else if(s1.value == "No" && s2.value == "No" && s3.value == "No") {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
  } 
}

</script>
```

I also tried the code on this page [Get selected value of option with multiple dropdown menus using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729155/get-selected-value-of-option-with-multiple-dropdown-menus-using-javascript). Can someone direct me to the correct solution or give me a hint? Sorry for the bad coding.

Comment: Where is the `s1` in the `if` statement declared?

Comment: `if(s1.value`  - at no stage in your code do you declare `s1`. How is s1 supposed to equal anything if it hasnt been defined? You should look into learning some basic Javascript before trying to hack things together.

Comment: I just signed up for a basic javascript with codecademy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define and init your variables `s1, s2, s3`. Without it you will receive errors

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById('s1'),
    s2 = document.getElementById('s2'),
    s3 = document.getElementById('s3');

function gotoPage(){

  if(s1.value == "Yes" || s2.value == "Yes" || s3.value == "Yes") {
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
  } else if(s1.value == "No" && s2.value == "No" && s3.value == "No") {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
  } 
}
```

```html
        <div>
          <label> A. Are you a programmer?</label>
          <select id="s1" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> B. Are you over 18?</label>
          <select id="s2" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label> C. Do you like apples?</label>            
          <select id="s3" name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
            <option value="#">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry for the dumb question. I signed up for a basica javascript class with codecademy.